# ¿Por qué en JavaScript al hacer document.write de un appendChild, me muestra este resultado?

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en JavaScript, pero ya programé en varios lenguajes... No logro entender el porque cuando hago :

```html
<body>
<div id="cont"> </div>

<script>
        const cont = document.getElementById("cont");
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText = "Lorem Ipsum";
        document.write(cont.appendChild(p));
</script>
```

Me muestra por pantalla : `[object HTMLParagraphElement]`

¿Seria un array de objeto HTMLParapraphElement?¿ Porque no me imprime el lorem Ipsum dos veces?

Comment: Pasandolo a otro lenguaje... es como cuando pongo en JAVA: ArrayList<int> array ; System.out.println(array);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `document.write` se utiliza para escribir texto solamente y `appendChild` retorna un objeto. No necesitas el `document.write`:

```html
<body>
<div id="cont"> </div>

<script>
        var cont = document.getElementById("cont");
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText = "Lorem Ipsum";
        cont.appendChild(p);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo este ejemplo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cont"></div>
<script>
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText = "Lorem Ipsum";
        const cont = document.getElementById("cont").appendChild(p)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Sería en todo caso que primero crees dicho elemento p
2. Después a ese elemento recién creado le añades el texto **"Lorem Ipsum"**
3. Al final obtienes el id que si existe desde el inicio con getElementById() y al final con la propiedad appendChild() le indicas que tendrá un elemento p creado

> Para este caso especifico const es el elemento padre y child es el
>   nodo que se va a agregar al final de dicho elemento

Para mayor información favor de consultar https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: Genioo!! Ahora entendi todo muchas gracias!!!.. Soy nuevo en stack Overflow. Como puedo agradecerte, mediante puntos? no entiendo nada jaj

Comment: la respuesta que consideras resolvió tu duda la puedes aceptar dando click en la palomita que esta justo a lado de ella; cualquiera de las 2 respuestas que te haya servido @JuanFrancoNarváez te anexaré una fuente confiable de consulta

Answer (score 1):

Veo que todas las respuestas se basan en hacer funcionar tu código, pero no responden a ninguna de tus preguntas.

**¿Seria un array de objeto `HTMLParapraphElement`?**

**No**, lo que estás viendo es la representación en String del objeto HTMLParagraphElement, que es justamente lo que ves si haces:

```js
console.log(document.createElement('p').toString())
// o
console.log(`${document.createElement('p')}`)
//o
console.log('' + document.createElement('p'))

// por ejemplo un objeto {} su representación es [object Object]
console.log('' + {});
```

En tú código `appendChild` devuelve el nodo insertado si se inserta y así es que ves [object HTMLParagraphElement].

Internamente `document.write` intentará llamar al método toString o similar si el objeto pasado no es un string.

**¿Porque no me imprime el lorem Ipsum dos veces?**

Porqué debería siquiera "imprimirlo" una vez?. Yo por "imprimir" entiendo que es mostrar algo por la consola de desarrollador.

Pero entendiendo tu pregunta y reformulándola a:

**¿Porque no me renderiza en el DOM el tag p dos veces?**

Porque solo lo insertas una vez dentro del div con `id = cont`. El cual ya estaba creado.

Si tu duda es si `createElement` inserta elementos en el DOM, la respuesta es no. De todas formas con el `document.write` estabas eliminando todo el contenido que hubiera.

Answer (score 0):

Tu caso es muy valido, solo te falto hacer un `innerText`
ya que sino vas a querer agregar `appendChild` en su elemento real.
Con `innerText` vas a volcar el contenido del nodo.-

```js
const cont = document.getElementById("cont");
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerText = "Lorem Ipsume";
        document.write(cont.appendChild(p).innerText);
```

```html
<div id="cont"> </div>
```